# Remove index.html from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in my website's root folder that contains the following code that should remove any index.html from the URL on my site.

For example:

- *"mywebsite.com/index.html"* should alter to *"mywebsite.com"* ; or
- *"mywebsite.com/subfolder/index.html"* should alter to *"mywebsite.com/subfolder/"*

My .htaccess file contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working when I upload to the server and clear my cache. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be working" exactly? Nothing happens? A redirect loop? Any error? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled in the server config?

Comment: Hi there, basically nothing happens, I can still see index.html in the URL. Server config is something I'm unaware of. I'll look into that thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the directives you've posted, so if "nothing happens" then the problem would seem to be "something else". If you don't have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file then it suggests `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled? What version of Apache are you on? Is this your server? `.htaccess` files (or "`.htaccess` overrides") are not enabled by default, you would need to have something like `AllowOverride All` in the appropriate section in the server config. (An indication they are not enabled is if you put some nonsense in the file and you still don't get an error.)